# Symfony: ircmaxwell/password-compat - $encoder->encodePassword returns false

Tags: php, symfony, bcrypt

I have a server with a PHP version less than 5.5 and I'm trying to program a user authentification using bcrypt in Symfony. So I installed ircmaxwell/password-compat but for some reason, the encoder always returns false. What I do is:

```
    $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
    $encoder =  $factory->getEncoder($user);
    $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword('test', $user->getSalt());
    die($encoded);
```

$encoded is always empty. I checked, the password.php in ircmaxwell is called and it returns a false in this line:

```
    if (!is_string($ret) || PasswordCompat\binary\_strlen($ret) != $resultLength) {
      return false;
    }
```

because the length of the String is 13, but resultLength is 60. I don't know much about bcrypt and this stuff so I just don't understand why this is happening. Can anyone give me a hint as to why this doesn't work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't see the obvious. The password-compat library clearly states under requirements that it requires php >= 5.3.7.
Well, turns out my php version is 5.3.3., so no wonder it doesn't work. 
Since updating the server isn't an option, I will abandon bcrypt and use something else.